# Scroll-dependent fade in and out text once reached a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text with `<p>` and `<h1>`. The text ends with one `<h1>`. 
I'd like to accelerate twice the Y translation of the `<p>` when I reach the the bottom of the document (the last h1 is in the middle of the page then), and I'd like the h1 to stay put in the middle of the page on its own.
But I'd like the `<p>` to scroll back if I scroll back up.

Is there a simple way to do that with jQuery?
I've tried a lot of solutions I've found on the web, but nothing satisfying.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var wScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var b = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    var c = ($(document).height() - wScroll - $(window).height()) * 2;
    var fade = 1 + c / 100;
    var trigger = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height() / 2;


    if(wScroll > b) {
      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('p').css({
          'transform' : 'translateY('+ c +'px)',
          'opacity' : ''+ fade +''
        })
      })

    }

});
```

```css
p, h1 {
  font-family: Baskerville;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 650px;
  color: #333;
}

p {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 33px;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

p:nth-child(2):first-letter {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 63px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 47px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

h1:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <h1 id="last">See ya!</h1>
    </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a first step.
If anyone has a better way to do it, I'll take it!

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){

// Variables for last paragraph

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var bottom = ($(document).height() - wScroll - $(window).height()) / 2 ;
  var fade = bottom / 100;


  // Last paragraph: fading & scroll x 2

  if(wScroll > $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height()){

    var offset = wScroll - $('h1#last').offset().top + $(window).height();

    // Select all the p, h1 et h2 but not those with id='last'

    $('p, h1, h2').not('#last').css({
      'transform': 'translateY(-' + offset * 0.4 +'px)',
      'opacity' : fade
    });

  }
  });
```

```css
p, h1 {
  font-family: Baskerville;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 650px;
  color: #333;
}

p {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 33px;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

p:nth-child(2):first-letter {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 63px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 47px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

h1:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare dictum ligula. Maecenas elementum suscipit nisl. Cras imperdiet leo ac felis dictum luctus. Pellentesque odio nisi, accumsan nec, scelerisque sed, consectetuer nec, justo. Sed tortor sapien, suscipit id, pulvinar vel, elementum id, lorem. Nullam consectetuer risus sit amet nibh. Vestibulum consectetuer, quam vitae euismod volutpat, magna magna consectetuer dui, et accumsan magna dui non nibh. Morbi adipiscing consequat erat. Vivamus quis massa eget orci fermentum laoreet. Morbi posuere purus. Duis feugiat lacus vel nisi. Aliquam ipsum felis, pretium sed, vehicula vel, dictum eget, nibh. Morbi turpis nulla, luctus viverra, pretium in, suscipit vitae, purus.</p>

    <h1 id="last">See ya!</h1>
    </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```